# strongswan: 07[IKE] no IKE config found for , sending NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-vpn, strongswan

I have configured a VPN gateway and a tunnel, but its not coming up getting below error.

charon: 13[IKE] no IKE config found for 10.0.1.211...125.17.97.4, sending NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN

Comment: and below is the config.

config setup

conn apigate-airtel-primary
authby=secret
keyexchange=ikev1
left=34.87.73.56
leftsubnet=35.240.245.123/32,35.187.234.149/32
leftid=@apigate
right=125.17.97.4
rightsubnet=125.16.134.64/29
rightid=@airtel-primary
pfs=yes
ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024!
esp=aes128-sha1,3des-sha1!
type=tunnel
ikelifetime=36600s
keylife=10800s
auto=start
keyingtries=3
dpdaction=restart

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that there was no match between the algorithms configured on the pair of VPN gateways.

Please note that, In IKEv1, the set of algorithms must be a complete match. In IKEv2, there must be one common algorithm between the two configurations [VPN Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/troubleshooting)

a) You should configure:

keyexchange=ike for IKEv1 and IKEv2 support, but initiate with IKEv2.

b) Also, change the ikelifetimefor IKEv2=36000s (10 hrs). You can see all the parameters for VPNs in GCP [Supported IKE ciphers](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/supported-ike-ciphers)

c) Also remember, EAP is not supported on Cloud VPN.

d) Finally a good guide for creating a VPN between GCP and Strongswan.[VPN between strongSwan and Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/using-cloud-vpn-with-strongswan).

Good Luck!

Comment: Can u plz check whether below configs are ok or not?

Comment: config setup
  charondebug="ike 3, mgr 3, chd 3, net 3"


conn apigate-airtel-primary
  authby=psk
  auto=start
  dpdaction=hold
  esp=aes128-sha1-modp1024!
  forceencaps=yes
  ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024!
  keyexchange=ikev1
  mobike=no
  type=tunnel
  left=34.87.6.243
  leftid=@apigate
  leftsubnet=35.240.245.123/32,35.187.234.149/32
  leftauth=psk
  leftikeport=4500
  right=125.17.97.4
  rightid=@airtel-primary
  rightsubnet=125.16.134.64/29
  rightauth=psk
  rightikeport=4500

Comment: I suggested change the IKE version. You should configure:
keyexchange=ike.